# How to check if the latest document is the same as 30 mins ago? [MongoDB, Node]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, document

I want to implement a kind of inactivity check in my stream data API to log a errormessage if the last added document in MongoDB is the same as the one 30 minutes ago. The api recieves data every three seconds. Can you give me a little help on how to achieve this? I have already thought of a setInterval() function that repeats every 30 mins, like this

```
var myVar = setInterval(check, 30000);

var latestDocu;

function check() {

if(latestDocu.equals(db.collection.find().sort( { _id : -1 } ).limit(1))[of 30 mins ago]){
    console.log('The input is idle')     
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you going so far and check DB for that? Check it at business layer.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `var lastUpdate = Date.now();` later when gonna insert new records update `lastUpdate`. Then it points to last update all the time and use it for your purpose.

Comment: You need to know how compare both documents, or how to get the document version of 30 minutes ago to compare with latest document?

Comment: The latter @Igor

Comment: If you are not sure about documents uniqueness then you need save last documents `hash` too.

Comment: Have you saved each document version in a new record (using date/time as reference)  each time you updated the document data? If you replace the document each time, you can get only the last saved version of your document.

Comment: Yeah, the documents are being saved. The format is as follows: '{"DateTime":'+'"'+currentTime+'"'+', "Temperature":'+temp+'}'

Comment: It doesnt necesarily to be compared by the way, it can also be achieved by just looking at the DateTime, cuz no matter what that needs to be updated every three seconds.